# Convert Function with SQL code to used with a array of records

Tags: delphi

I have a simple table in database with several fields
ID,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5 : Integer and R : Float
i usually use this function with several parameters to get a total on R

```
 function Total(const X : array of NUMBER): Float;
  begin
QUERY.SQL.Add('Select Sum(R) as Total from Table where
'    ( CASE WHEN :P1  = 0 THEN A1 = A1 ELSE A1 = :Y1 END ) '+
'and ( CASE WHEN :P2  = 0 THEN A2 = A2 ELSE A2 = :Y2 END ) '+
'and ( CASE WHEN :P3  = 0 THEN A3 = A3 ELSE A3 = :Y3 END ) '+
'and ( CASE WHEN :P4  = 0 THEN A4 = A4 ELSE A4 = :Y4 END ) '+
'and ( CASE WHEN :P5  = 0 THEN A5 = A5 ELSE A5 = :Y5 END ) '+
'and ( CASE WHEN :P6  = 0 THEN B1 = B1 ELSE B1 = :Y6 END ) '+
'and ( CASE WHEN :P7  = 0 THEN B2 = B2 ELSE B2 = :Y7 END ) '+
'and ( CASE WHEN :P8  = 0 THEN B3 = B3 ELSE B3 = :Y8 END ) '+
'and ( CASE WHEN :P9  = 0 THEN B4 = B4 ELSE B4 = :Y9 END ) '+
'and ( CASE WHEN :P10 = 0 THEN B5 = B5 ELSE B5 = :Y10 END ) ');
if X[1] = 0  then QUERY.ParamByName('P1').Value := 0 ;
if X[2] = 0  then QUERY.ParamByName('P2').Value := 0 ;
if X[3] = 0  then QUERY.ParamByName('P3').Value := 0 ;
if X[4] = 0  then QUERY.ParamByName('P4').Value := 0 ;
if X[5] = 0  then QUERY.ParamByName('P5').Value := 0 ;
if X[6] = 0  then QUERY.ParamByName('P6').Value := 0 ;
if X[7] = 0  then QUERY.ParamByName('P7').Value := 0 ;
if X[8] = 0  then QUERY.ParamByName('P8').Value := 0 ;
if X[9] = 0  then QUERY.ParamByName('P9').Value := 0 ;
if X[10] = 0  then QUERY.ParamByName('P10').Value := 0 ;
QUERY.ParamByName('Y1').Value := X[0];
QUERY.ParamByName('Y2').Value := X[1];
QUERY.ParamByName('Y3').Value := X[2];
QUERY.ParamByName('Y4').Value := X[3];
QUERY.ParamByName('Y5').Value := X[4];
QUERY.ParamByName('Y6').Value := X[5];
QUERY.ParamByName('Y7').Value := X[6];
QUERY.ParamByName('Y8').Value := X[7];
QUERY.ParamByName('Y9').Value := X[8];
QUERY.ParamByName('Y10').Value := X[9];
QUERY.Open ;
Result := QUERY.FieldByName('Total').Value ;
end;
```

for example a have a

```
0,0,0,0,2,3,1,2,3,4,1.00
1,0,0,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,2.00
1,0,0,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,3.00
0,0,0,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,4.00
```

When a use Total(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0) function return a 10.
When a use Total(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0) function return a 5.
When a use Total(1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0) function return a 1. and so on

I Have a record with the same fields
and a array of records
T_Rec: array of T_Record;
I need to hava a function to do the same as function Total

```
function Total1(const X : array of NUMBER): Float; 
var R : Real ;
begin
R := 0 ;
 for i := 0 to Length(T_Rec)-1 do
    begin
      How to do this SQL Hack  
        CASE WHEN :P1  = 0 THEN A1 = A1 ELSE A1 = :Y1 END 
     in condisions ?
     ......
     R := R + T_Rec.R
end;
```

Any Help be appreciate.
Thanks.

Comment: Please show the missing record and variable definition. btw: I don't understand your question. Maybe you could rephrase it?

Comment: Record is the same as the table a1-a5, b1-b5 :integer and R :float

Comment: `float` is unknown to Delphi - that's the culprit. Glad I could help.

Comment: Ok.Float or Extended or Real this is not the problem.I need help with the condisions in the loop to solve that.

Answer (score 0):

**Float** is unknown to Delphi use **Real** instead.

**NUMBER** is unknown to Delphi use **Integer** instead.

When you want to change your query string don't use parameter, Parameters slow down your query. Parameters useful when you set query string and change only parameters value.

Why you add (A1 = A1) to your condition, it's useless and slow down your query.

My prefer function is like this:

```
function Total(const X : array of Integer): Real;
const
  FieldNames : array [0..9] of String = ('A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5');
var
  s : String;
  i : integer;
begin
//condition section
  s := '';
  for i := 0 to 9 do
    if (X[i] <> 0) then s := s + ' AND (' + FieldNames[i] + ' = ' + IntToStr(X[i]) + ')';
  if (s <> '') then
  begin
    System.Delete(s, 1, 4); //remove first AND
    s := ' WHERE' + s;
  end;

  // query section
  QUERY.SQL.Add('Select Sum(R) as Total from Table' + s);
  QUERY.Open;

  Result := QUERY.FieldByName('Total').Value;
end;
```

Now let's define T_Record something Like this :

```
type
  T_Record = record
    A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, B1, B2, B3, B4, B5 : Integer;
    R : Real;
  end;
```

You can search in **T_Rec: array of T_Record** with this function :

```
function Total1(const X : array of Integer): Real;
var
  R : Real;
  i : Integer;
  TRecord : T_Record;
begin
  R := 0 ;
    for TRecord in T_Rec do
    begin
      if (((X[0] = 0) or (TRecord.A1 = X[0])) and
          ((X[1] = 0) or (TRecord.A2 = X[1])) and
          ((X[2] = 0) or (TRecord.A3 = X[2])) and
          ((X[3] = 0) or (TRecord.A4 = X[3])) and
          ((X[4] = 0) or (TRecord.A5 = X[4])) and
          ((X[5] = 0) or (TRecord.B1 = X[5])) and
          ((X[6] = 0) or (TRecord.B2 = X[6])) and
          ((X[7] = 0) or (TRecord.B3 = X[7])) and
          ((X[8] = 0) or (TRecord.B4 = X[8])) and
          ((X[9] = 0) or (TRecord.B5 = X[9]))) then
        R := R + TRecord.R;
    end;
    Result := R;
end;
```

Good luck